# How to efficiently iterate through a complicated function that outputs a dataframe?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I essentially need to iterate through a set of values for parameters `A,B,C` to generate a table of results that will help me analyze the importance of such parameters. This is for a program in R.

Let's say that:

1. `A` goes from `rangeA = 1:10`
2. `B` goes from `rangeB = 11:20`
3. `C` goes from `rangeC = 21:30`

The simplest (not most efficient) solution that I currently use goes something like this:

```
### here I create this empty dataframe because I add on each tmp calc later
res <- data.frame()

### here i just create a random dataframe for replicative purposes
dataset <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))


ParameterAdjustment() <- function{

  for(a in rangeA){
  for(b in rangeB){
  for(c in rangeC){

    ### this is a complicated calculation that is much more
    ### difficult than the replicable example below
    tmp <- CalculateSomething(dataset,a,b,c)

    ### an example calculation
    ### EDIT NEW EXAMPLE CALCULATION
    tmp <- colMeans(dataset+a*b*c)
    tmp <- data.frame(data.frame(t(tmp),sd(tmp))

    res <- rbind(res,tmp)
  }
  }
  }

return(res)
}
```

My problem is that this works fine with my original dataset that runs calculations on a 7000x500 dataframe. However, my new datasets are much larger and performance has become a significant issue. Can anyone suggest or help with a more efficient solution? Thank you.

Comment: I think that you're going to need to provide a more realistic example of `CalculateSomething`. This is currently rather trivial, since `tmp` is a scalar. Although, TBH, your `res <- rbind(res, tmp)` doesn't provide a key-value pair, which means that as currently structured getting the "optimal" values of a,b,c from `res` seems needlessly painful.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to pre-allocate memory for res and use `res[k] <- tmp` instead of the huge number of calls to assignment and rbind

Comment: I have edited the example calculation to make it more appropriate

Comment: Also `sd(colMeans(dataset + a*b*c)) == sd(colMeans(dataset) + a*b*c) == sd(colMeans(dataset))` since sd(X + a*b*c) = sd(X) + 0 where X is a RV and a,b,c are constants

Comment: i understand that those properties of mean and sd exist. I am just using a simple calculation to show my point. My function doesn't use calculations with such properties. It is actually calculation portfolio performance statistics and thus must save values in a dataframe in a similar fashion to the edited question

Comment: what if i am trying to collect a bunch of calculations stored in the form of a dataframe? I cannot simple preallocate the space

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language the above is, so not sure how relevant this is but here goes: Are you outputting/sending the data as you go or collecting all the display-results in memory then outputting them all in one go at the end? When I've encountered similar problems with large datasets and this approach has helped me out a few times. For example, sending 10,000s of data-points back to the client for a graph, rather than generating an array of all those points and sending that, I output to screen after each point and then free up the memory. It still takes a while but that's unavoidable. The important bit is that it doesn't crash.

Comment: the language I am using is R. I do not seem to be having an issue with crashing. It is more of a performance issue. I do not really need to graph the data, I just need to have the data stored in a variable so that I can access it for further computation/manipulation later